# Prism: have to call RaiseCanExecuteChanged() explicitly

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, delegatecommand

Below is a very simple `Prism.Wpf` example with a `DelegateCommand` that has both `Execute` and `CanExecute` delegates.

Suppose that `CanExecute` depends on some property. It seems that Prism's `DelegateCommand` doesn't re-evaluate `CanExecute` condition automatically when this property changes, as `RelayCommand` does in other MVVM frameworks. Instead, you have to call RaiseCanExecuteChanged() explicitly in the property setter. This leads to a lot of repetitive code in any non-trivial viewmodel.

Is there a better way?

*ViewModel*:

```
using System;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;

namespace PrismCanExecute.ViewModels
{
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _title = "Prism Unity Application";
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    }
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _name, value);

            // Prism doesn't track CanExecute condition changes?
            // Have to call it explicitly to re-evaluate CanSubmit()
            // Is there a better way?
            SubmitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        SubmitCommand = new DelegateCommand(Submit, CanSubmit);
    }

    public DelegateCommand SubmitCommand { get; private set; }
    private bool CanSubmit()
    {
        return (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name));
    }
    private void Submit()
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(Name);
    }

}
}
```

*View*:

```
<Window x:Class="PrismCanExecute.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    Title="{Binding Title}"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
<Grid>
    <!--<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" />-->
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Name: " />
            <TextBox Width="150"
                     Margin="5"
                     Text="{Binding Name,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Width="50"
                    Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
                    Content="Submit" Margin="10"/>
            <!--<Button Width="50"
                    Content="Cancel"
                    IsCancel="True" Margin="10"/>-->
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @l33t explained, this is by deign.  If you want the DelegateCommand to monitor VM properties for changes automatically, just use the ObservesProperty method off of the delegateCommand:

```
var command = new DelegateCommand(Execute).ObservesProperty(()=> Name);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. It's performance related.

Though, you *can* replace the Prism `DelegateCommand` with a custom-made command that does what you want. E.g. [this](https://github.com/SonyWWS/ATF/blob/master/Framework/Atf.Gui.Wpf/DelegateCommand.cs) implementation seems to do the trick. However, I would not recommend using it. You will very likely run into performance problems if you have lots of commands.

Also, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7336453/419761).

Comment: Thanks. I also found the following links quite useful: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459183/how-to-make-the-canexecute-trigger-properly-using-prism-6?rq=1) and related (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313190/observesproperty-method-isnt-observing-models-properties-at-prism-6)