# Prism 6 DelegateCommand ObservesProperty code

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Hi Good day i'm just new with WPF and MVVM design pattern and i've learned a lot from the blogs and videos of sir BRIAN LAGUNAS in PRISM.. but just want to ask a noob question..whats wrong with my code it doest work for me... any help is very appreciated thanks.
here's my code :

**MY VIEW MODEL**

```
public class Person : BindableBase
{
    private myPErson _MyPerson;
    public myPErson MyPerson
    {
        get { return _MyPerson; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _MyPerson, value);
        }
    }

    public Person()
    {
        _MyPerson = new myPErson();
        updateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Execute, CanExecute).ObservesProperty(() => MyPerson.FirstName).ObservesProperty(() => MyPerson.Lastname);

    //    updateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Execute).ObservesCanExecute((p) => CanExecute); /// JUST WANNA TRY THIS BUT DUNNO HOW
    }

    private bool CanExecute()
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyPerson.FirstName) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyPerson.Lastname);
    }

    private void Execute()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("HOLA");
    }

    public DelegateCommand updateCommand { get; set; }
}
```

**myModel**

Declared to another Class File

```
public class myPErson : BindableBase
{
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _firstName, value);
        }
    }

    private string _lastname;
    public string Lastname
    {
        get { return _lastname; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _lastname, value);
        }
    }
}
```

**View**
Xaml Code

```
<Window x:Class="Prism6Test.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:myVM="clr-namespace:Prism6Test.ViewModel"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <myVM:Person x:Key="mainVM"/>
    </Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource mainVM}">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="217,103,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MyPerson.FirstName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="217,131,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MyPerson.Lastname,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding updateCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,159,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've Already read this but it doesnt work for me.. and cant understand how can i properly code it.. please help me ragarding this matter ..HOPE for any reply soon..thx

[ObservesProperty method isn't observing model's properties at Prism 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313190/observesproperty-method-isnt-observing-models-properties-at-prism-6)

Comment: What is the Button doing?

Comment: Post a message box "HOLA".

Comment: Okay. Now i see it. what is the problem of the code? You do not see something in the TextBoxes?

Comment: it is binded to a DelegateCommand prop. and it should execute "Execute" method.. but before it will execute the Button is disable until the two textboxes are filled up thx for you comment @JensHorstmann

Comment: it is binded to a DelegateCommand prop. and it should execute "Execute" method.. but before it will execute the Button is disable until the two textboxes are filled up...but in my case it doesn't work.. thx for your comment @JensHorstmann

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You can`t use complex datamodel like you want, so try it

```
private myPErson _MyPerson;
    public myPErson MyPerson
    {
        get { return _MyPerson; }
        set
        {
            if (_MyPerson != null)
                _MyPerson.PropertyChanged -= MyPersonOnPropertyChanged;

            SetProperty(ref _MyPerson, value);


            if (_MyPerson != null)
                _MyPerson.PropertyChanged += MyPersonOnPropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private void MyPersonOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        updateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
```

2) Change your constructor

```
public Person()
    {
        MyPerson = new myPErson();
        updateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Execute, CanExecute);
    }
```

Comment: @Neil Mark this answer as solution please, if it helped you

Answer (score 3):

First i have to say something about your naming. Name your Classes clear. Call your **ViewModel** e.g. `PersonViewModel` or just `ViewModel` when your application is not that big and not `Person`, because `Person` is obviously the **Model**. Moreover `myPErson` is a very bad name, because it is very similar to your other `Person` class and you should [PascalCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285866/why-relaycommand) your class names.

Now **to your code**. I know nothing about `Prism` so my code depends on the `MVVM` pattern only without the support of the Prism Libraries.

First i want to change the **Model** `Person`. The class looks very easy in my code (just uses auto properties):

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        this.LastName = string.Empty;
        this.FirstName = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

The `PersonViewModel` is a littlebit more complex because it implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. I am also using the very common [RelayCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285866/why-relaycommand) which you can find in the link under the accepted answer.

```
public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Person person;

    private ICommand updateCommand;

    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        this.Person = new Person();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Person Person
    {
        get
        {
            return this.person;
        }

        set
        {
            this.person = value;

            // if you use VS 2015 or / and C# 6 you also could use
            // this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Person));
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Person");
        }
    }

    public ICommand UpdateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.updateCommand == null)
            {
                this.updateCommand = new RelayCommand<Person>(this.OpenMessageBox, this.OpenMessageBoxCanExe);
            }

            return this.updateCommand;
        }
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private void OpenMessageBox(Person person)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hola");
    }

    private bool OpenMessageBoxCanExe(Person person)
    {
        if (person == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person.FirstName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person.LastName))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I cleared up your View a bit, because it is much shorter now. but all in all everything stayed the same. i just renamed the properties and stuff:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <wpfTesst:PersonViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Person.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Person.LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Button" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Person}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

All in all i would recommend to you to use the common MVVM pattern without the Prism Library. When you understood MVVM good you still can go for Prism.
Hope it helps.

Comment: thank for you suggestion sir @Jens Horstmann..and this will help me to improve my coding..out of curiosity just wanna use PRISM library and study regardin it.. can i ask from you a link, book for my reference sir? for future study..please please...thx very much

Comment: @Neil do what you want with your links =P

Comment: haha.. any suggested link from you sir ^_^.... for my future reference sir..i studying..please please ... @Jens Horstmann

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish
I think you can google yourself. i can't find the tutorial i had.

Answer (score 0):

View Xaml Code

```
<Window x:Class="Prism6Test.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:myVM="clr-namespace:Prism6Test.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
```

You are missing the ViewModelLocator

```
    xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
```